# Discrepancy in a rate of change question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, related-rates

Upon solving the following rates of change question from a first year undergraduate course in calculus, I came across two possibilities for the ODE modelling the situation, and I can't understand why. The question is as follows:

> An initially unpolluted lake of $10^9$ litres has a river flowing through it at $10^6$ litres per day. A factory is built which discharges $10^4$ litres per day of pollutant into the lake. Assume that the total volume of liquid in the lake remains at a constant $10^9$ litres.

If we let $x(t)$ be the amount of pollutant in the lake in litres at time $t$, then the amount of pollutant at time $t + \delta t$ should be $$x(t + \delta t) = x(t) + 10^4 \delta t - \lambda_1 10^6 \delta t $$ where $\lambda_1$ is the fraction of the $10^6 \delta t$ litres of water expelled from the lake that is pollutant. The fraction $\lambda_1$ should be the concentration of pollutant in the water after clean water and pollutant have been introduced over the time $\delta t$, so

\begin{align}
\lambda_1 = \frac{x(t) + 10^4 \delta t}{10^9 + 10^4 \delta t + 10^6 \delta t}
\end{align} Hence
$$
\frac{x(t + \delta t) - x(t)}{\delta t} = 10^4 - \frac{x(t) + 10^4 \delta t}{10^9 + 10^4 \delta t + 10^6 \delta t} 10^6 
$$ Taking the limit as $\delta t \to 0$ we obtain that $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 10^4 - 10^{-3} x$$ which is what I thought the solution was.

The problem is that if we let $c(t)$ be the amount of clean water in the lake in litres at time $t$, then by a similar argument we have that $$ \frac{dc}{dt} = 10^6 - 10^{-3}c$$ which does not respect the condition $\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dc}{dt} = 0$, which comes from $x + c = 10^9$. The solution at the back of the booklet gives the solution $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 10^4 - \frac{10^4 + 10^6 }{10^9} x$$ The only way I can think of arriving at this solution is to assume that $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 10^4 - \lambda x$$ and $$ \frac{dc}{dt} = 10^6 - \lambda c$$ and solving for $\lambda$ using the condition that $x' + c' = 0$.

My question is: What is wrong with my solution and why does this discrepancy occur?

---

As pointed out in Lutz Lehmann's comment and Ryan G's answer, the rate at which fluid flows out of the system is $10^4 + 10^6$ litres per day, not $10^6$ litres per day.

Fixing this, we have that

$$x(t + \delta t ) = x(t) + (\text{added pollutant in the time } \delta t) - (\text{pollutant that has left the system in time } \delta t)$$ The pollutant added to the system in the time $\delta t$ is $10^4 \delta t$. The total amount of fluid that has exited the system in the time $\delta t$ is $(10^4 + 10^6) \delta t$, and so

$$ x(t + \delta t) = x(t) + 10^4 \delta t - \rho (10^4 + 10^6) \delta t \tag{1}$$ where $\rho$ is the concentration of pollutant in the fluid that has flown out of the system over the time $\delta t$. We could calculate $\rho$ in a couple of ways:

- We could assume that firstly, the pollutant and clean water enter the system so that the total amount of fluid in the system is $10^9 + (10^4 + 10^6) \delta t$. At this point $$\rho = \frac{x(t) + 10^4 \delta t}{10^9 + (10^4 + 10^6) \delta t}$$ and afterwards this excess fluid flows out of the system.
- The second way is to just take $\rho$ to be the concentration of pollutant at time $t$, i.e. $$\rho = \frac{x(t)}{10^9}$$

In either case, from $(1)$ we obtain that

$$ \frac{x(t+ \delta t) - x(t)}{\delta t} = 10^4 - \rho (10^4 + 10^6) $$ and so
\begin{align}
\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \frac{x(t+ \delta t) - x(t)}{\delta t} &= 10^4 - \left( \lim_{\delta t \to 0} \rho \right)(10^4 + 10^6) \\ &= 10^4 - \frac{10^4 + 10^6}{10^9} x(t)
\end{align} I.e. we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} = 10^4 - \frac{10^4 + 10^6}{10^9} x
\end{align} which is the correct answer.

Comment: The two sources add a combined volume of $10^6+10^4$ per day, this has then also to be the volume speed of the outflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we let $x(t)$ be the amount of pollutant in the lake in litres at time $t$, then the amount of pollutant at time $t + \delta t$ should be $$x(t + \delta t) = x(t) + 10^4 \delta t - \lambda_1 10^6 \delta t $$ where $\lambda_1$ is the fraction of the $10^6 \delta t$ litres of water expelled from the lake that is pollutant. The fraction $\lambda_1$ should be the concentration of pollutant in the water after clean water and pollutant have been introduced over the time $\delta t$, so \begin{align}
> \lambda_1 = \frac{x(t) + 10^4 \delta t}{10^9 + 10^4 \delta t + 10^6 \delta t}
> \end{align}

Firstly, the rate of total outflow equals $(10^6+10^4)$ L/day, instead of just $10^6$ L/day.

Secondly, here's the correct model (which is consistent with the book's answer):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \text{rate of increase of pollutant}\\=\text{rate of pollutant inflow}-\text{rate of pollutant outflow}\\=\text{rate of pollutant inflow}\\-\text{pollutant concentration}\times\text{rate of total outflow}\\=10^4 - \frac x{10^9} ({10^6 + 10^4})\\=10^4 - \frac{10^6 + 10^4}{10^9} x.$$

---

Re: your **addendum**

Rewrite all instances of $\rho$ to $\rho(t)$ to remind self that it varies with time, and notice that $\displaystyle\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \rho=\displaystyle\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \rho(t)=\rho(t),$ by definition.

So, attempting to express $\rho$ in terms of both $t$ and $\delta t$ (as you did in the first bullet point) is unnecessary. That expression for $\rho$ is anyway incorrect (e.g., the total fluid is always $10^9$ litres), even though the error doesn't break the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I think the main issue was getting the outflow incorrect. After fixing that, is my reasoning correct? Not as concise as your derivation though.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to note what is wrong with my model? I can't see where I'm going wrong. Is it in the calculation of $\lambda_1$?

Comment: I am especially interested since after adjusting that issue, my argument does give the same differential equation as the solution in the book.

Comment: @Stogies Would you mind to show your revised argument (after said adjustment) as an addendum to your Question, showing that it reaches the same differential equation? (Please don't edit away the original argument, which continues to be relevant to the flow of Q&A on this page.) Doing so helps clarify your original argument or even figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it means a lot to me to get this feedback. I have edited the question to include the calculation with the correct outflow.

Comment: @Stogies You're most welcome! I've expanded my answer in response.

Comment: Incremental models are usually constructed in forward Euler mode. @Stogies, in your $λ$ computation you are using a backwards Euler strategy. As you noted, in the limit $δt\to 0$ both are the same, but the forward Euler terms are usually more simple.